# Page preinit & Page load getting called twice only on the page having reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

As title says, Only for the page containing the report viewer, preinit & load are getting called twice.

Already tried making script manager's script mode to release. Then those events are getting called countless times.

First time it is non-postback & second time it is postback. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set  `AsyncRendering` property of `reportviewer` to `false`.
Also, you can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252090.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by setting AutoEvenWireup=true on the page's propertys.